# Magento 1.7.0.2 USPS Shipping Method Issue

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods, usps

It started out as users not being able to check out - when they added items to their cart through the one page checkout they would get to the shipping methods then get kicked back to the cart page. I have now since disabled USPS and everything works with UPS except, in system configuration I get a blank page when I try to change settings in the ship method settings.

I have getting the following errors:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Usps contains
>   1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement
>   the remaining methods
>   (Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Abstract::_doShipmentRequest) in
>   /public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Usps.php
>   on line 913, referer:
>   http://domain.com/index.php/admin/system_config/edit/section/shipping/key/9c01422374d1f5cdc61d4f9ac85c6a00/

Running magento 1.7.0.2

Really need some help - I have tried applying the patch from the magento website to fix the issue but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The version on this file that is in the official release of Magento 1.7 there is a function `_doShipmentRequest`. I assume  your file is broken in some way. I would suggest that you need to re download the file so that you have all the functions you need but here is the single function if you need.

```
/**
 * Do shipment request to carrier web service, obtain Print Shipping Labels and process errors in response
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $request
 * @return Varien_Object
 */
protected function _doShipmentRequest(Varien_Object $request)
{
    $this->_prepareShipmentRequest($request);
    $result = new Varien_Object();
    $service = $this->getCode('service_to_code', $request->getShippingMethod());
    $recipientUSCountry = $this->_isUSCountry($request->getRecipientAddressCountryCode());

    if ($recipientUSCountry && $service == 'EXPRESS') {
        $requestXml = $this->_formUsExpressShipmentRequest($request);
        $api = 'ExpressMailLabel';
    } else if ($recipientUSCountry) {
        $requestXml = $this->_formUsSignatureConfirmationShipmentRequest($request, $service);
        if ($this->getConfigData('mode')) {
            $api = 'SignatureConfirmationV3';
        } else {
            $api = 'SignatureConfirmationCertifyV3';
        }
    } else if ($service == 'FIRST CLASS') {
        $requestXml = $this->_formIntlShipmentRequest($request);
        $api = 'FirstClassMailIntl';
    } else if ($service == 'PRIORITY') {
        $requestXml = $this->_formIntlShipmentRequest($request);
        $api = 'PriorityMailIntl';
    } else {
        $requestXml = $this->_formIntlShipmentRequest($request);
        $api = 'ExpressMailIntl';
    }

    $debugData = array('request' => $requestXml);
    $url = $this->getConfigData('gateway_secure_url');
    if (!$url) {
        $url = $this->_defaultGatewayUrl;
    }
    $client = new Zend_Http_Client();
    $client->setUri($url);
    $client->setConfig(array('maxredirects'=>0, 'timeout'=>30));
    $client->setParameterGet('API', $api);
    $client->setParameterGet('XML', $requestXml);
    $response = $client->request()->getBody();

    $response = simplexml_load_string($response);
    if ($response === false || $response->getName() == 'Error') {
        $debugData['result'] = array(
            'error' => $response->Description,
            'code' => $response->Number,
            'xml' => $response->asXML()
        );
        $this->_debug($debugData);
        $result->setErrors($debugData['result']['error']);
    } else {
        if ($recipientUSCountry && $service == 'EXPRESS') {
            $labelContent = base64_decode((string) $response->EMLabel);
            $trackingNumber = (string) $response->EMConfirmationNumber;
        } else if ($recipientUSCountry) {
            $labelContent = base64_decode((string) $response->SignatureConfirmationLabel);
            $trackingNumber = (string) $response->SignatureConfirmationNumber;
        } else  {
            $labelContent = base64_decode((string) $response->LabelImage);
            $trackingNumber = (string) $response->BarcodeNumber;
        }
        $result->setShippingLabelContent($labelContent);
        $result->setTrackingNumber($trackingNumber);
    }

    $result->setGatewayResponse($response);
    $debugData['result'] = $response;
    $this->_debug($debugData);
    return $result;
}
```